# How to ignore characters before and after my pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help creating a regex (in java) to find a pattern like:

```
(30.6284, -27.3493)
```

It's roughly a latitude longitude pair. Building from smaller pieces, I've come up with this:

```
String def = "\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*(\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)";
```

which works ok if I don't have any characters before or after the parenthesis. So this fails:

```
"hello (30.6284, -27.3493)   "
```

but it'll work if I remove the "hello " before and the trailing whitespace. How can I ignore any other sequence of characters before and after the expression?

Thanks

Comment: Use a different matching function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to find and extract multiple instances of the pattern in your text.

```
    String def = "\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*(\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)";
    String text = "hello (30.6284, -27.3493)  (30.6284, -27.3493) ";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(def);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(text.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hello (30.6284, -27.3493)   ";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*(\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*(\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)).*","$1"));
```

output:
(30.6284, -27.3493)

Note that if you're going to be looping through to find things, I would use something like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*(\\((\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*(\\-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)).*").matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.start()+ " " + m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this using this website: http://regexpal.com/ and http://www.regextester.com/

```
\(-?\d+\.?\d+, -?\d+\.?\d+\)
```

This will match, but not capture, and probably isn't in your language specific format (but should be easily modifiable. To support capturing you could use this one:

```
\((-?\d+\.?\d+), (-?\d+\.?\d+)\)
```